# Make Edition Upgrade in a SQL cluster scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question in regards to Enterprise Edition to Standard Edition Upgrade. I need to move a SQL Cluster based on couple of SQL Evaluation Enterprise Edition to a licensed Standard Edition. How do I use the new license key?

OS: Windows Server 2012 Std Edition
SQL Server: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 4):

You aren't able to "downgrade" SQL Server Editions from Enterprise (including Evaluation) to Standard Edition. The [Supported Version & Edition Upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx) article details supported upgrade paths.

In the upgrade matrix in the above link, you will notice that the section for Evaluation Edition includes the following note:

```
 Upgrading from Evaluation Enterprise (a free edition) to any of the 
 paid editions is supported for stand-alone installations, 
 but is not supported for clustered installations.
```

On a Failover Cluster Instance, in order to change from Evaluation Edition to Standard Edition, you will need to uninstall SQL Server, and re-install using Standard Edition. The same is true in all cases (clustered or standalone) if you are using Enterprise Edition, or Evaluation Edition with any Enterprise-only features.

Comment: Hi AMtwo, honestly I already test this scenario and I've got a good results testing the with the SELECT @@VERSION, but I don't know if the CLUSTER can change the results.

Comment: The upgrade matrix I linked to in my answer shows that evaluation-->Standard is possible, however, if your installation is using any *Enterprise* features (as you eluded to in your question), then downgrading is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, sure... but in my case I don't usa any ENTERPRISE features

Comment: Please take a look at the edits I've made to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's a lot for link the documentation. 
Which step do you suggest to perform on cluster to do this update (uninst/inst)?

My intent it is to reduce the amount if time where Sql server (both) are unavailable.

Thank you very much
Alto